# Invalid Scopes: read_stream, when I try to connect with Facebook API in WCM

Tags: facebook, ibm-wcm

I got this error when I try to connect with Facebook API.

[image: Invalid Scope:read_stream]
I have developed application in WCM(IBM), could anyone help on get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

`read_stream` is deprecated and has been removed a very long time ago: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Don´t ask for the permission in the login process and the error will disappear.

Comment: Can please explain in detail, where we can set the permissions

Comment: i don´t know where to do that in that weird "wcm", but i suggest not using some very old platform and use the official sdks instead. for example, the js sdk: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/